# PYTHON: Memory Error - MultinomialNB.partial_fit() - 17k classes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Hi i am new to Python SKLearn and ML in general. Im encountering a Memory Error when using MultinomialNB partial fit, Im trying to do Multi Label Classification on the DMOZ directory data.**

**My questions**:

- What am i doing wrong? Is it my lack of memory or is the data wrong?
- Am i using the right approach ?
- Anything i can do to improve my appraoch ?

**Approach**:

Store DMOZ DB directories into MongoDB/TokuMX

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "54e758c91d41c804d8ace196"
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.awn.com/",
      "description": "Provides information resources to the international animation community. Features include searchable database archives, monthly magazine, web animation guide, the Animation Village, discussion forums and other useful resources.",
      "title": "Animation World Network"
    }
  ],
  "labels": [
    "Top",
    "Arts",
    "Animation"
  ]
}
```

Itterate over the `docs` array and pass `docs` elements into my classifier function.

**Vectorizer and Classifier**

```
    classifier = MultinomialNB()
    vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(
            stop_words='english', 
            strip_accents='unicode', 
            norm='l2'
         )
```

**My classifier function**

```
def classify(doc, labels, classifier, vectorizer, *args):

    r = requests.get(doc['url'], verify=False)

    print "Retrieving URL = {0}\n".format(doc['url'])

    if r.status_code == 200:
        html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
        doc['content'] = []


        tags = ['font', 'td', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p', 'title']
        for tag in tags:
            for x in html.xpath('//'+tag):
                try:
                    bag_of_words = nltk.word_tokenize(x.text_content())
                    pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(bag_of_words)

                    for word, pos in pos_tagged:
                        if pos[:2] == 'NN':
                            doc['content'].append(word)

                except AttributeError as e:
                    print e

        x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc['content'])

        #if we are the first one to run partial_fit, pass all classes
        if len(args) == 1:
            classifier.partial_fit(x_train, labels, classes=args[0])
        else:
            classifier.partial_fit(x_train, labels)

        return doc
```

X: `doc['content']` consists of a array with NOUNS. (600)

Y: `labels` consists of a array with labels inside the mongo document showed above. (3)

Classes `args[0]` consists of array with all the (UNIQUE)`labels` in the database. ( 17490)

Running inside VirtualBox on a Quadcore laptop with 4gb ram assigned to VM.

Answer (score 0):

What are the 17490 unique labels? There will be one coefficient for each label and each feature, which is likely where your memory error comes from.